# Teamcity 7.1.4a working SVN roots failing

Tags: windows-server-2003, svn, teamcity

I just installed TeamCity 7.1.4a over a working 7.1.2 installation. All of my SVN roots are now failing with `403 forbidden` errors. SVN is logging that attempts from TC are now `anon(ymous)` and *not* using the configured SVN User/PW in TeamCity that's been working fine.

I don't see anything in the change log for 7.1.4 that would cause this. If I back-rev the installation 7.1.2 works fine.

Server is Win2k3. VisualSVN Server.

**Update** --

Looks like a configuration issue. Looking at the logs, the older version of TeamCity was logging in as `System` not the `SVNuser` configured in the TC VCS Root UI. TeamCity [has a known issue](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Known+Issues#KnownIssues-SubversionRepositoriesWithNTLMAuthorization) where this could happen, but I do not have Anonymous logins allowed in VisualSVN so not sure why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: Make sure Basic Authentication is enabled on VisualSVN Server

tl;dr version ...

The [`svnkit.http.ntlm=jna`](http://andersaskenryd.blogspot.com/2009/10/using-secure-subversion-from-teamcity.html) fix was put in when TC was first setup to overcome the perceived problem of logging in. This had the effect of using the TC Service's user with VisualSVN's Integrated Windows Authentication. Previous to 7.1.4a that ended up being a user with access to the SVN repository. With 7.1.4a the user turned into "Anonymous" (even though the server doesn't have any Anonymous access enabled).

Removing the `jna` fix, and turning on VisualSVN's basic auth so TC can send proper credentials fixed the problem.